# How to destroy session after clicking the logout button?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've read alot of problems about logout that it keeps going back to the recent page which is the account is still logged in, I have the same problem with `asp.net core mvc`, I've researched alot too, and I always see only `2014` answers and its `outdated`. I also wanted to destroy the the `Cookie Session` but this following codes are not working:

```
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

And when I transfer them to `HttpContext`, `Abandon()` can't be recognized

```
HttpContext.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Session.Clear() //Not deleting the Session Cookie Also
```

Here is my code. In my controller:

```
public IActionResult logmeout()
    {
      
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("operator_name", "");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg_id", "");

        HttpContext.Session.Remove("operator_name");
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("reg_id");

        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

All of them is not working and I tested it out one by one creating them as a comment, and it only redirect to the homepage. Anyone knows?

EDIT:

I forgot to add this  in `IActionResult`

```
if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("operator_name") == "" || HttpContext.Session.GetString("reg_id") == "" || HttpContext.Session.GetString("operator_name") == null || HttpContext.Session.GetString("reg_no") == null)

        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

It also not working like this

```
public IActionResult logmeout()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("operator_name") == "" || HttpContext.Session.GetString("reg_id") == "" || HttpContext.Session.GetString("operator_name") == null || HttpContext.Session.GetString("reg_no") == null)

        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }


        HttpContext.Session.SetString("operator_name", "");
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("reg_id", "");

        HttpContext.Session.Remove("operator_name");
        HttpContext.Session.Remove("reg_id");

        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Have you got `AddSession` and `UseSession` in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Yes I have, That's why I don't know why its not working

Comment: You say that it only redirects you to the home page, but from the code you've shared, redirecting to the home page is the only result you return. Is the setting not working or is it just the clearing? Have you put `UseSession` between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`? You need to be setting `operator_name`, `reg_id` and `reg_no` otherwise it will go in first redirect

Comment: Let me try again

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: `All of them is not working` What is this mean? After `HttpContext.Session.Clear();`, You can also use `HttpContext.Session.GetString("xxx")` to get the value?

Comment: After searching on, Inspect element of my localhost, It's very clear that the `HttpOnly = true` can't be deleted, but I have a `Timeout` for my `Session`, so I assume that it's working fine, but the thing is, when I click the back button, It keeps going back to recent page where the account still logged in, so Im assuming that the `Session` still not clearing after logout

Comment: When you login, The information about user is stored in cookie,  So when you want to logout, You can try to delete the cookie about the user, and then check if the account is still logged in.

Comment: It's actually deleting the cookie, but the prob is when I clicked the back button of the browser, it keeps going back to the dashboard. Is there any solutions to block or keep the login panel stay after the logout?

Comment: You can't specify like `return RedirectToAction()` in your logout method? After delete the cookie, The page will also show account is still logged in?